# How to do if A and B and C equal 1 in a Windows Batch File?

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I am writing a batch file that needs to check if three variables are all equal to the same thing at the same time.

What I thought would work was this:

```
if %A% AND %B% AND %C% EQU 1 goto YES
```

It sadly it did not work.  Usage of this in my file:

```
:init
set A=0
set B=0
set C=0
```

Then if goes through and gets variables A B and C set to 1 when you tell it to.

```
if %A% and %B% and %C% EQU 1 (
    goto YES
) ELSE (
    goto NO
)
```

Then the file goes on and does other things not necessary to this question.

Please answer soon.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@echo off &setlocal
:init
set A=0
set B=0
set C=0

if %A% equ %B% if %B% equ %C% (goto:yes) else goto:no
```

Comment: Thank you Endoro and Jon.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Simply chain the IFs:

```
IF %A% EQU 1 IF %B% EQU 1 IF %C% EQU 1 goto YES
```

You can follow this up with a straight `GOTO NO` which will function as the "else" branch (or you can do `IF`/`ELSE` as in your original code, it's a matter of preference).

Note that writing the above as

```
IF "%A%"=="1" IF "%B%"=="1" IF "%C%"=="1" GOTO YES
GOTO NO
```

will work even without command extensions being enabled.

Comment: Quick question, will I be able to use the IF var EQU number (
goto yes
)ELSE(
goto no
)
?

Comment: @downvoter: Please help me improve this answer by leaving a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options here:

1- If the possible values for the variables are just 0 and 1,  then the equivalent numeric operation for the Boolean AND  operator is multiplication:

```
set /A result=A * B * C
if %result% EQU 1 (
   goto YES
) else (
   goto NO
)
```

2- You may made clearer the fact that you are nesting two or more `IF`'s with the purpose to assemble a Boolean AND operator this way:

```
set AND=IF
if  %A% equ 1  %AND%  %B% equ 1  %AND%  %C% equ 1  goto YES
goto NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the accepted answer does not fully answer the question as asked. As is shown by the test applied, all it does it go to YES if A=B=C and will do so if A=B=C=anyvalue (like 0, as demonstrated). The question was if A=B=C=1, which would require an extra test.

Depending on quite what values may be assigned to A,B and C, it may be possible to test A=B=C=1 (as specified) quite easily:

```
if %A%%B%%C%==111 goto yes
```

but that assumes that there's no possibility that for instance A=1,B undefined and C=11.